# ¿Como evitar que php / apache ejecute comandos como cat o ls?

Tags: php, apache, httpd

tengo un archivo que ejecuta ls y cat

```
<?php
echo exec('ls / | xargs');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo exec('cat /etc/passwd | xargs');
echo PHP_EOL;
?>
```

me gustaria saber como puedo evitar que se ejecute desde el navegador

Answer (score 1):

Ir al `php.ini` y ir al apartado `disable_functions` y añadir allí exec y todas las funciones que quieras separadas por comas y sin paréntesis

Para saber donde se encuentra el archivo puedes utilizar `phpinfo();`